# Automating Calls to New Google Sheets Add-ons

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm building a Google Spreadsheet that uses an official add-on to pull data from Google Analytics using the new add-on store. What I'd like to have it do is automatically refresh the data every day at some time and email me the info. The add-on requires you to manually click "Run Reports" from its drop-down menu in order to refresh the data.

The heart of the question is this: can you call an add-on menu option from a script? Is there a google-script API or handle or reference that will allow me to grab a line from the drop-down Google Spreadsheet menus that is attached to a black-box code?

Answer (score 2):

I've looked in these places on the [Google Apps Developer site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/):

- [Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/)
- [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/)
- [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

but wasn't able to find a solution. Therefore I created an feature request in the issue tracker: **[3803](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3803)**

Comment: Well, thanks. I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score -1):

The "goog-ly" way to this is to have the sheet pull in live data every time you look at it, and just set a calendar reminder for yourself to check the sheet every day. The calendar reminder can be configured (in Google Calendar, Outlook, and other calendars) to send you an email reminder that would include a link to the sheet.

If you need help getting the sheet to update automatically, this link may help:

> http://www.computerworld.com/slideshow/detail/79661

It uses very simple data, but the main thing isn't the specific data as much as it is encapsulating your data in a script, and using a trigger to run the script when the sheet opens.

Comment: Right, I'm just having trouble with setting it up so that it can pull the data while using the new Out-Of-The-Box apps without human intervention.

Comment: @EmmettR. Is the problem it that you can't get it to refresh data automatically when you view the sheet, or that the data is so time sensitive that viewing it at times that vary by a few minutes (or even an hour an so) will cause problems?

Comment: The first. It's not very time-sensitive, I would just like to get it to refresh automatically.

Comment: @Emmett R. Updated.

Comment: I really don't think you're apprehending the problem at hand. I'm not dealing with a normal script. I need to know if there is any kind of handle, reference, API or call to reach a google sheets menu item that is linked to a black-box. I edited my question to try and clarify.

Comment: The OP is talking about the new _Add-on_ functionality in the new Google Spreadsheet, not a normal script.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra And I'm talking about writing a new script to call the add-on, so that you can then use a trigger to run it automatically when the sheet loads.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Show us the money !! Dutch ancestors....?